# How do Loom and Grammarly's Chrome Extensions work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm coding a web extension that can analyze speech in real-time. This extension can be useful for various scenarios, such as having meetings or practicing presentations. While working on this project, I noticed that Loom is capable of recording the entire screen while accessing the system's microphone. Grammarly, on the other hand, can detect when users are typing and provide feedback on the grammar and tone of their sentences.

It got me thinking:

1. How do they manage to achieve these functionalities? Specifically, how is Grammarly able to detect the typing action? How does it apply to audio processing?
2. Are these tasks easy, medium, or hard? If it's hard, what makes it hard?